# Oracle Daily count/average over a year

Tags: oracle, count, average

I'm pulling two pieces of information over a specific time period, but I would like to fetch the daily average of one tag and the daily count of another tag. I'm not sure how to do daily averages over a specific time period, can anyone provide some advice? Below were my first ideas on how to handle this however to change every date would be annoying. Any help is appreciated thanks

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct chargeno), to_char(chargetime, 'mmddyyyy')  AS chargeend 
FROM batch_index WHERE plant=1 AND chargetime>to_date('2012-06-18:00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd:hh24:mi:ss') 
AND chargetime<to_date('2012-07-19:00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd:hh24:mi:ss')
group by chargetime;
```

---

```
The working version of the daily sum
SELECT to_char(bi.chargetime, 'mmddyyyy') as chargtime, SUM(cv.val)*0.0005 
FROM Charge_Value cv, batch_index bi WHERE cv.ValueID =97
AND bi.chargetime<=to_date('2012-07-19','yyyy-mm-dd')
AND bi.chargeno = cv.chargeno AND bi.typ=1
group by to_char(bi.chargetime, 'mmddyyyy')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like in the first one you want to change the group to the day - not the time... (plus i dont think you need to specify all those 0's for seconds..)

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct chargeno), to_char(chargetime, 'mmddyyyy')  AS chargeend 
FROM batch_index WHERE plant=1 AND chargetime>to_date('2012-06-18','yyyy-mm-dd') 
AND chargetime<to_date('2012-07-19','yyyy-mm-dd')
group by to_char(chargetime, 'mmddyyyy') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

not 100% I'm following your question, but if you just want to do aggregates (sums, avg), then do just that.  I threw in the rollup just in case that is what you were looking for

```
with  fakeData as(
  select trunc(level *.66667) nr 
      , trunc(2*level * .33478) lvl --these truncs just make the doubles ints
      ,trunc(sysdate+trunc(level*.263784123)) dte --note the trunc, this gets rid of the to_char to drop the time
  from dual
connect by level < 600
) --the cte is just to create fake data
--below is just some aggregates that may help you
select sum(nr) daily_sum_of_nr
     , avg(nr) daily_avg_of_nr
     , count(distinct lvl) distinct_lvls_per_day
     , count(lvl) count_of_nonNull_lvls_per_day
     , dte days
  from fakeData
 group by rollup(dte)
```

--if you want the query to supply a total for the range, you may use rollup ( http://psoug.org/reference/rollup.html )